List of all connected, compact 2-manifold M with or without boundary with Euler characteristic $-2\leq\chi(M)\leq2$ up to homeomorphism
The case for connected, compact surface (2-manifold) without boundary is obviously $\mathbb{S}^2$, connected sum of projective planes, and connected sum of tori. For the case with connected, compact surface with boundary, I proved the following two lemmas:

Every compact surface with boundary is homeomorphic to a compact surface with finitely many open cells removed.


If $\tilde{S}$ is a surface with boundary obtained from surface $S$ by removing $n$ open 2-cells, then $\chi(\tilde{S})=\chi(S)-n$, and $\tilde{S}$ is orientable if and only if $S$ is orientable.

So, I reduced the case to where it could be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$ with $1,2,3$, or $4$ open 2-cells removed; $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with $1,2,$ or $3$ open 2-cells removed; $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ with $1$ or $2$ open 2-cells removed; $\mathbb{T}^2$ with $1$ or $2$ open 2-cells removed; and lastly $\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2\#\mathbb{RP}^2$ with $1$ open 2-cell removed. By orientability, some of them are immediately are nonhomeomorphic.
However, the problem I am having is proving the remaining ones are homeomorphic or nonhomemorphic to others one, e.g. $\mathbb{S}^2$ with $1$ open 2-cell removed vs $\mathbb{S}^2$ with $2$ open-cells removed. I am thinking of using fundamental groups, but I do not know how to compute the fundamental groups of either of them. I was also struggling with proving it for ones with different surface without boundary, e.g., $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $\mathbb{T}^2$.
I appreciate any help I can get.

Orientability is not the only topological invariant to be applied in this situation. Each of the following three quantities is a topological invariant:

The Euler characteristic
The number of boundary components
Orientability

You can work your way down your list to verify: for any two surfaces on that list, at least one of those three invariants has distinct values.
For example, $\mathbb S^2$ with one open cell removed has $1$ boundary component, whereas $\mathbb S^2$ with two open cells removed has two boundary components.
For another example, $S^2$ with two open cells removed has Euler characteristic $0$, whereas $T^2$ with two open cells removed has Euler characteristic $-2$.

For the Euler characteristic, my professor said that it is topologically invariant if the number of holes (open 2-cells removed) is equal to 0. So, in the case with $\mathbb{S}^2$ with two holes and $\mathbb{T}^2$ with two holes, are the Euler characteristics topological invariant because they both have two holes?

@StrugglingWithAlgTop The Euler characteristic is invariant under homeomorphism, i.e. if $M$ and $M'$ are two homeomorphic compact manifolds (say) then $\chi(M) = \chi(M')$. That's what the term "topological invariant" means.

@BenSteffan Is this also true for compact manifolds with boundary? The textbook I am using only mentions it for compact manifold.

@StrugglingWithAlgTop The Euler characteristic is a topological invariant of all spaces for which it is defined. This includes all compact manifolds with or without boundary, all finite CW-complexes, ...
